# daemon process in iphone SDK 4.1?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

is there any API to enable background process...(in IPHONE SDK 4.1)?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the conventional sense, no. Apple allow a restricted number of use cases, such as VoIP and music, but other background processes are not allowed. This is [well documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on the iOS Developer Centre.